# Rails Nested form and Dropzone

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, dropzone.js

i'm striving to make a simple dropzone work on a product form with nested images form but after search a lot and change the code i would like to know if dropzone support nested form, because i can't find it in the doc.

anyway my code is:

```
$('#images').dropzone({// PDF dropzone element
  maxFilesize: 2, // Set the maximum file size to 256 MB
   maxFiles: 10,
    dictDefaultMessage: "drop your images here",
    paramName: "product[images_attributes][][foto]",
  addRemoveLinks: true, // Don't show remove links on dropzone itself.
 dictRemoveFile: 'Remover'

    // rest of code
 //
 });
```

<

```
%= form_for @product, :html => {:multipart => true}  do |p| %>
  <div class="block margin_top">

 <%= p.fields_for(:images,  html: { multipart: true, id: "images",class: "dropzone"}) do |i| %>
     <div class="fallback">

            <%= i.file_field :photo %><br>
            <%= i.submit "Save" %>
          </div>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

Comment: Is the dropzone not appearing?

Comment: thank's for your interest @Pavan, and right, is not appearing

Comment: Have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29487666/carrierwave-with-dropzone-js-is-it-possible-to-use-these-with-nested-attributes

Comment: thank's but did not worked